# Using PowerMockito to mock a class with @Inject variables and static methods

Tags: java, spring, unit-testing, mockito, powermockito

I am trying to use a power mock to mock a class with @Injects and static methods called in another class constructor. But for some reason it seems to be throwing MissingMethodInvocationException in PowerMockito.when.

```
@Named
public class InstanceLocationWrapperFactory {

    @Inject
    private InstanceLocation instanceLocation;

    private static InstanceLocation internalInstanceLocation;

    @PostConstruct
    private void load(){
        internalInstanceLocation = instanceLocation;
    }

    public static InstanceLocation getInstance(){
        return internalInstanceLocation;
    }

}
```

I am trying to use it to instantiate a value inside the constructor of another class like as follows. (InstanceLocation is a interface which is implemented by DefaultInstanceLocationImpl class.)

```
class A{

    InstanceLocation instance;

    A(){
        instance = InstanceLocationWrapperFactory.getInstance();
    }

    public String myMethod(){
        /* using instance here to do some logic*/
    }
}
```

I am trying to write a test like this

```
@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)
@PrepareForTest({A.class, InstanceLocationWrapperFactory.class})
public class ATest {

@Test
public void myTestCase1{
    InstanceLocation instanceLocation = mock(DefaultInstanceLocationImpl.class);
    PowerMockito.mockStatic(InstanceLocationWrapperFactory.class);
    PowerMockito.when(InstanceLocationWrapperFactory.getInstance()).thenReturn(instanceLocation);
    when(instance.getMethod()).thenReturn("something");
}
```

But when i run the above code for some reason i keep getting the below error for the line **PowerMockito.when(InstanceLocationWrapperFactory.getInstance()).thenReturn(instanceLocation);**.

```
org.mockito.exceptions.misusing.MissingMethodInvocationException: 
when() requires an argument which has to be 'a method call on a mock'.
For example:
    when(mock.getArticles()).thenReturn(articles);

Also, this error might show up because:
1. you stub either of: final/private/equals()/hashCode() methods.
   Those methods *cannot* be stubbed/verified.
   Mocking methods declared on non-public parent classes is not supported.
2. inside when() you don't call method on mock but on some other object.
```

Can someone please help me understand if I am doing something wrong or missing something here.